# How to document one file with functions?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I have a python file with functions (lib.py), without classes. Each function has the following style:

```
def fnc1(a,b,c):
    '''
    This fonction does something.

    :param a: lalala
    :type a: str
    :param b: hahaha
    :type b: int
    :param c: hohoho
    :type c: int

    :rtype: int

    '''

    print a
    d = b + c

    return d
```

I just want to document each function (inputs and outputs) with Sphinx.

After doing *sphinx-quickstart*, I defined the path in **conf.py** with my lib.py.
But the output HTML file (welcome page) is empty.

If I write myself in **index.rst**:

```
.. function:: func1(a,b,c)
    This fonction does something.

    :param a: lalala
    :type a: str
    :param b: hahaha
    :type b: int
    :param c: hohoho
    :type c: int
    :rtype: int
```

it is ok, it shows the inputs and outputs in html file.
But how to do it automatically?

Normally, I think, it must to do it in **lib.rst** after doing *sphinx-apidoc -o*, 
but in **lib.rst** there is only:

```
lib module
==================

.. automodule:: lib
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Can somebody explain me step by step what I must do exactly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, when you run *sphinx-quickstart*, be sure you select *autodoc*:

```
autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/N) [n]: y
```

Then, in the generated *index.rst* I usually add *modules* to include all the modules automatically (watch identation).

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   modules
```

After this *sphinx-apidoc -o* does generates documentation for me.

I wrote a guide to use Sphinx for Python code used in embedded systems, but the first steps of the Guide might be useful to you as well:

[How to generate sphinx documentation for python code running in an embedded system](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_generate_sphinx_documentation_for_python_code_running_in_an_embedded_system)

[EDIT]

Here is a step-by-step list:

1. Create lib.py
2. Create documentation folder: `mkdir doc`

   ```
   ├── doc/
   └── lib.py
   ```
3. Enter doc/: `cd doc`
4. Execute `sphinx-quickstart`  (Be sure to select `autodoc: y`, `Makefile: y`)
5. Edit *conf.py* to specify sys.path: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))`
6. Edit index.rst and specify *modules* in the toctree:

   ```
   .. toctree::
       :maxdepth: 2

       modules
   ```
7. Execute `sphinx-apidoc -o . ..`
8. Generate the html output: `make html`
9. View your documentation: `firefox _build/html/index.html`

Comment: thanks for your response! Yes, I have selected "yes" for autodoc. If I do _sphinx-apidoc -o_ without adding _modules_ in **index.rst**, it creates **lib.rst** and **modules.rst**, but they are empty. If I add _modules_ in **index.rst** and after I do _sphinx-apidoc -o_: it creates the same **lib.rst** like in 1st case, but there is the IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error when it tries to create **modules.rst**.

Comment: yes, i have saw already your Sphinx guide, and I did almost the same.

Comment: I reproduced your scenario and added a step-by-step list, please check if that works.

Comment: Ok! It works! Thank you very much, @jcarballo!
In fact, if we add _modules_ in **index.rst**, 
it needs to precise that all **rst** files must be in the same place where **index.rst** is.

So it is better to do _sphinx-apidoc -o_ directly being in the same directoty where the **index.rst** is
(in my case it is **source** directory).

Comment: Glad it worked! Thanks for your note on the placement of .rst files, I didn't knew about that one.