# How to give system path while making documentation in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, ubuntu-13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 version and make project of python in **pyDev** using **Eclipse** IDE. I want to make documentation of it. For this purpose I follow the link [Documenting Python code using Sphinx](http://raxcloud.blogspot.com/2013/02/documenting-python-code-using-sphinx.html).

**Following Procedure:**

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -A "Zeb Mustafa" -F -o docs MyPackage/src/
```

After that what path should should I insert here:

```
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('/home/zeb/MyPackage/src/'))
```

I also try this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('MyPackage/src/'))
```

Above both line give **error**:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `0,'
```

How I give the path so that conf.py should know what code use for making documentation?

After a lot of digging this problem . I ultimatly do like:

```
$ make html
```

And

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ cd docs/
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~/docs$ make html
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~/docs$ sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees  . _build//html
```

All the .html file are empty. Not shown any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

If it doesn't work, please provide the folder structure of your project.

See also [Python-Sphinx: How to document one file with functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354768/python-sphinx-how-to-document-one-file-with-functions/20355305#20355305), the example commands could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,When I Edit conf.py to specify sys.path: `#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))` ,same problem when I write this by using terminal the error:`bash: syntax error near unexpected token `0,'`. I also uncomment the path in `conf.py` but again nothing change